# Why is my boolean field still showing up as part of the request body after I used @JsonIgnore and @JsonIgnoreProperties?

Tags: json, jackson

In my Swagger documentation, for POST requests, it should not show the boolean field in the request body.

I want to ignore the `booleanValue` field in the DTO class below:

```
public class MyDto {
    private String stringValue;
    @JsonIgnore
    private int intValue;
    private boolean booleanValue;
}
```

I have tried using `@JsonIgnore` and `@JsonIgnoreProperties`, but it is not working.

```
1.  @JsonIgnore
    private boolean booleanValue;

2.  @JsonIgnoreProperties(value = { "booleanValue"})
    public class MyDto {
      /* ... */
    }
```

How can I ignore the boolean field in the `MyDto` class?

Answer (score 1):

is your boolean field starts with isSomething or hasSomething? if yes, then the @Jsonignore doesn't work on it. you need to change it to "something"

Answer (score 1):

You will need to change dataType from boolean to Boolean, then it will work.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use [`@ApiModelProperty`](http://docs.swagger.io/swagger-core/v1.5.0/apidocs/io/swagger/annotations/ApiModelProperty.html) and set the [`hidden`](http://docs.swagger.io/swagger-core/v1.5.0/apidocs/io/swagger/annotations/ApiModelProperty.html#hidden()) element to `true`:

```java
@ApiModelProperty(hidden = true)
private boolean booleanValue;
```

Comment: The below one is not working
@ApiModelProperty(hidden = true) . in my project i am using spring fox swagger and using 2.4.0 version